# Auto increment of identity to a specific number in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a DB where ID is bigint and auto incremented identity column.Works fine but suddenly it rises and starts from specific number ?
[image]

i want to know why it is happening and how can i continue the increment from 152 again ????

Comment: Why does it matter which value is in that column?

Comment: Its just happen many times and the sequence is lost.And not sure how?

Comment: ziad has already answered why it happens, but does it matter?

Comment: this behaviour is not an issue under normal circumstances and is normal, as you can read in the answer from ziad. if it is an issue for you and you **need** to have a complete sequence then you'd better explain the real requirement behind this need otherwise you'll get comments like mine or @LasseV.Karlsen's one: this is not an issue, forget about it

Comment: The usual reason why this is an issue beyond the "hey, I just noticed that ..." observation is that people care about these numbers. They might be customer numbers or order numbers or whatnot, displayed to users. That is an incorrect usage of an identity column, at least if you don't want holes in the sequence, or jumps like this. The general rule is that if you care about the actual value (ie. whether it is 10 or 29786489) then you should not use an identity column, you should use a sequence and control when new numbers are generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all perfectly normal. Microsoft added sequences in SQL Server 2012, finally, i might add and changed the way identity keys are generated. Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-2012-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is) for some explanation.

If you want to have the old behaviour, you can:

1- use trace flag 272 - this will cause a log record to be generated for each generated identity value. The performance of identity generation may be impacted by turning on this trace flag.

2- use a sequence generator with the NO CACHE setting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)